# What is template in component Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components

can someone explain me what does it mean "template" in @Component({}). For example i've create my component

```
@Component({
selector: 'delete'
template: 'What i must write here?. If i write code here, this code will be at view? or i should write code here and the same in view?
```

I've read documentation, but can't understood for what this component

Comment: Please check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ There should be enough examples out there that make it quite clear what the `template` should contain. Have you tried to search before you asked?

Answer (score 3):

You pass the HTML that defines how the view should look like that Angular2 creates to `template`. Alternatively you can pass `templateUrl` with a path to an HTML file that should be used to create the view.

Comment: If i write simple template for component, and write this component on view. This teplate will be initialize and showed on view?

Comment: Yup, that's the idea.

Comment: but if i alreay have html view with code, and when i create new Component on Controller(this controller has component with templeteURL to view) and write template on this new Component, my html code will be changed to template code?

Comment: You can only have `template` **or** `templateUrl` but not both. Either you get an error or one of them is ignored (I don't use Angular2 with TS and can't tell for sure which one).

Answer (score 2):

template is the html view for the component you are creating. So typically what I like to do is create two files,

myfile.component.ts
myfile.component.html

In the ts file is the typescript / javascript logic for the view,

In the html file is the html for the view and is the page that will be viewed.

Then in the template field in the ts file specify the path to the html file,

.ts file

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './myfile.component.html',
})
export class MyfileComponent {

  constructor() { }

}
```

.html file

```
<div>
My html file is being viewed now!
</div>
```

You can also directly serve html from the .ts file. To do that you could use template instead of `templateUrl` then you would not need the html file.

```
 @Component({
      template: `
    <h1>My First Angular 2 multiline template</h1>
    <p>Second line</p> 
    `
    })
    export class MyfileComponent {

      constructor() { }

    }
```

notice where the ticks are, it must be formated like that.

So to simplify multiple views, in my app this is how I structure it,

first views files.

```
file1.component.ts
file1.component.html
```

Second views files.

```
file2.component.ts
file2.component.html
```

etc.

So each time I want to create a new view I create two new files. One for js logic and one for the html view.

Remember each time you create a new component you have to register it in the app.module.ts file and the routes file.

app.module

```
//Layouts
import { MyfileComponent }                  from './views/myfile.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MyfileComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        routing
    ],
    providers: [ 
    Guard,
    Auth,
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Routes

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full', },
    { path: 'home', component: MyfileComponent, data: { title: 'myfile View' }
];
```